# Mathematica 13.3 - Bug: Incorrect markers in ListStepPlot with option PlotLayout->Stacked

Tags: plotting, marker

To reproduce - just take example from help and add an option `PlotLayout -> "Stacked"`:

```
ListStepPlot[Table[p Range[6], {p, {3, 7, 11, 13}}], Center, 
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic, Joined -> False, PlotLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

Markers will not match the lines:

[image]

OS: Windows 10

Comment: I don't see any question here ... Bugs should be reported to the [WRI](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?topic=feedback) not to the StackExchange, because we cannot fix them :) If you are looking for a workaround, then please formulate the question in this way.

Comment: Please read the `bugs` tag wiki: it can only be added as a tag to a post after the bug has been vetted by the community.

Comment: That said, this doesn't happen in my version of Mathematica: `"12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"`.

Comment: Version 14.0, Windows 10 and 11 I get the same behavior as the OP.